# Not quitting from For loop

Tags: python

I am beginner in python ,I am using for loop to repeat steps to do and check for condition using if ,But it doesn't come out of for loop if the if  is satisfied

```
    for i in range (1 , 30):
        admin_reports_alertReports.click_("followUp")
        admin_reports_alertReports.click_("messaged")
        admin_reports_alertReports.click_("messagedResponded")
        admin_reports_alertReports.click_calculate_delivery_recipients_btn()
        if not admin_reports_alertReports.assert_element_visible("followupRecipientCount", "1 recipients"):
            admin_reports_alertReports.click_("cancelButton")
        else:
           break
    admin_reports_alertReports.click_("followuptemplateSelection")
    admin_reports_alertReports.set_("followupSearchBox", "Create New Template\n")
```

Comment: There is no infinite loop on your code. I think function's code have it.

Comment: What does `admin_reports_alertReports.assert_element_visible("followupRecipientCount", "1 recipients")` return exactly? Note that Python will evaluate things to be "truthy", so a string or non-zero number will be true. Does that function return a boolean?

Comment: Just curious, what the purpose of mixing snake_case and camelCase?